# Provenance of upright piano labelled Joint Stock

Tags: piano

I have come to own this upright piano labelled "Joint Stock". No other label or mark visible. I am unable to find out anything about its provenance. Any ideas?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Theres a site called pianohistory.info/names.html.  It does not give you a definite answer to your question but it may shed some light on this for you.

Comment: Any name on the harp inside? Overstrung, underdamped? Iron frame? What does the middle pedal do?

Comment: No other name visible, particularly heavy body. The person who delivered it (it had to be moved) suggested that it might be former SU, but he said it was just a guess.

Comment: Is there no serial number on the cast iron frame?

Comment: Could it possibly relate to "stock" as in (eg) summer stock, the theater term?

Comment: @Balazs is "SU" USSR?

Comment: Yes Soviet Union.

Answer (score 1):

Weirdly enough,  some history texts refer to a "joint-stock piano" (no capitals) as a standard item.  [Example](https://historyengine.richmond.edu/episodes/view/5171):

> First, Dickens wrote that many boarding houses had a joint-stock
> piano. Apparently, to Englishmen this would seem like a luxury not
> fitting for workers.

Many piano mfrs became "joint-stock" companies, which doesn't help us either. However, my guess is that this particular piano might be a 'custom' item produced by some manufacturer to celebrate 'going public' and becoming a joint-stock corp.    Maybe someone who is an expert in Dickens & his history knows more about the origin of this term.

Comment: Your comments, and some further googling, lead me to this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Belarus_(pianos)

Comment: I think this is our piano: http://www.belpiano.narod.ru/7a.jpg

Comment: Listed as B-7 on http://www.belpiano.narod.ru/7.htm

Comment: @Balazs nice find.  I still think you will probably find some more information on the frame.  There's usually a serial number there, or at least a name.  Serial numbers are also sometimes found on hidden surfaces of wooden parts, for example inside the key slip (the piece of wood that sits at the ends of the keys and helps keep the keyboard in place) or on the key bed (which is hidden from view by the key slip).

Comment: @Balazs  you should post that info as an answer.   Great work!

Comment: Right now I am away from the piano but will check frame when I am back.

Answer (score 1):

It was suggested that I post an answer. Comments in Carl's answer lead me to this site

http://www.belpiano.narod.ru

Their piano B7 looks about right:

http://www.belpiano.narod.ru/7.htm

http://www.belpiano.narod.ru/7a.jpg

So it looks like the piano is by Joint-stock company Muzinstrument - Borisov, from Belarus.